First activity is destroyed and recreated when the user is moved from First Activity to Second and back to First on Samaung A34
For one of the user who's using Samsung Galaxy A34 with Android 14 and RAM is 8 GB.
I have implemented dropdown selection in a different activity where the user clicks on dropdown for selection from First Activity he will be taken to Second activity where all the options are populated in recyclerview, Once the user selected the option he will be moved back to First Activity and OnActivity is getting is called with the intent data.
This is working fine for all the users but not for one of the user.
what is observed?
when the user is moved back to first activity with data, the first activity is destroyed and recreated and OnCreate() method is called.
Not able to fix this issue nor replicate it on other mobiles. Can you please share your thoughts/inputs and solutions for this issue.
Thanks in advance
I checked the same on different mobile devices(Physical) but i could not replicate the same on other Mobiles.

This is normal and expected behavior. Read this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#use_onsaveinstancestate_as_backup_to_handle_system-initiated_process_death

Tip: open developer settings and enable "Don't keep activities" - this will let you test your app in extremely punishing lifecycle scenario where all activities are destroyed as soon as they leave the foreground.

How do you navigate between activities? Post the code you are using to move from one Activity to the other. Are you calling finish()? Also post the relevant parts of your manifest so we can see how the activities are configured.
